# Performance issue of animation in Iphone 3GS having IOS 4.2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios-4.2, iphone-3gs

Hi
I wrote a gaming application for **iphone 4.0** and it's working fine there, and the same application showing low frame rate with **Iphone 3GS**  having **IOS 4.2**.
I did google and some forums said that core animation is slower and they suggest to use **OpenGL ES**, after that I ported my application for **OpenGL ES** and guess, it was worst than core animation.
What might be the issue any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get more information on your problem by running the OpenGL ES Analyzer profiling tool in XCode. There's a really good video on these tools in the 2010 WWDC videos - session 419, I think.